# JNI calling a Java Method from C++

Tags: android, methods, java-native-interface

I am having a problem with JNI, calling a method from C++ to Java.

I am trying to call a void method that takes a boolean. My java code is the following:

```
public void setStatus(boolean bool) {
    // Do stuff...
}

public native void initialize(int defaultPort);
```

In my C++ code, I am making a struct to hold the env and object and pass it to a thread:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_device_client_HostConnection_initialize
  (JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jint port)
{
    struct javaInfo* data = (struct javaInfo*) malloc(sizeof(struct javaInfo));
    data->env = env;
    data->javaObjHost = obj;

    pthread_t pth;
    pthread_create(&pth, NULL, startServer, (void *) data);

    free(data);
}
```

In the actual function, I am trying to obtain the class and then the MethodID and then call the void method, as follows:

```
void *startServer(void* arg) {
    struct javaInfo* data = (struct javaInfo*) arg; 
    JNIEnv* env = data->env;
    jobject javaObjHost = data->javaObjHost;

    cls = env->GetObjectClass(javaObjHost);
    mid = env->GetMethodID(cls, "setStatus", "(Z)V");
    if (mid == 0) {
        exit(-1);
    }
    env->CallVoidMethod(javaObjHost, mid, true);
}
```

It is hard for me to debug with JNI. I have tried putting a breakpoint in Eclipse in setStatus() but it never gets called. exit() is not called as well. The programs stomps for a second or two, then continues. I am not sure what is going on.

Could anyone please help me?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot pass env pointers to other threads. You need to join the thread to the JVM.

In the original thread, called `GetJavaVM` to obtain a `JavaVM` pointer:

```
JavaVM *vm = 0;
env->GetJavaVM(&vm);
```

Then in the other thread, attach the VM to that thread and get a new `env` pointer:

```
vm->AttachCurrentThread(&env, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked! I had to do two tiny modifications: env->GetJavaVM(&vm); and vm->AttachCurrentThread(&env, 0); Thanks a lot! You helped a lot!

Comment: Actually, I am having a little problem. Sometimes AttachCurrentThread crashes my code. It gives me a SIGSEGV: I/DEBUG   ( 4633): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr 00000010

Comment: I've added a check to make sure vm != NULL but that hasn't helped. Any clue please?

Comment: The address 00000010 implies jumping to an offset from NULL. Try logging the value of your vm pointer from the thread, it may be NULL when there's a problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I actually fixed it. I was calling free(data)  but the thread would not have read the content of the void *arg, so it would try to read a null pointer. I just removed the free. Thank you.